# Is it obligatory to admonish someone who is sinning?

Tags: halal-haram, behavior

If I see someone sinning for example, committing shirk. Am I obligated to tell them? I have heard that we should conceal the sins of each other. But I also heard that if we see someone sinning we should tell them because it’s advising them to do good. If I do not inform them of their sin is that haram? I am very confused.

Comment: Enjoining good and forbidding wrong (الأمر بالمعروف والنهي عن المنكر ) is an obligation, or at least approved depending on the circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

Allaah Azza Wa Jalla says in al-Qur'aan (interpretation of the meaning):

> "And let there be [arising] from you a nation inviting to [all that is]
> good, enjoining what is right and forbidding what is wrong, and those
> will be the successful."

<sup>3:104 (https://quran.com/3/104)</sup>

It was also narrated in an authentic hadith:

> "[...] I heard the Messenger of Allah as saying: He who amongst you sees
> something abominable should modify it with the help of his hand; and
> if he has not strength enough to do it, then he should do it with his
> tongue, and if he has not strength enough to do it, (even) then he
> should (abhor it) from his heart, and that is the least of faith."

<sup>Sahih Muslim, 49a (https://muflihun.com/muslim/1/79)</sup>

If the person is an outwardly righteous Muslim and does not openly commit sin, you should - in general - conceal his sin in front of others, but **it is mandatory upon every Muslim to correct a person who commits sin**, and give him sincere advice [[1](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/96662/is-he-sinning-if-he-sees-an-evil-action-and-does-not-denounce-it)][[2](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/201472/concealing-peoples-sins-is-a-matter-that-is-subject-to-further-discussion)].

And Allaah Azza Wa Jalla knows best.